# passing std::array variable as argument

Tags: c++, c, std

I need help in resolving an issue which i am facing .

I would want to have a function prototype which accepts two different types of argument at two instances.

For example shown below:
I have a structure as shown below:

```
         typedef struct BufferStruct
         {
            unsigned long    BufferType;
            unsigned long    TheAddress;
          } Buffer;
```

I have a function named Test and this function should accept two different types of argument

```
  1) std::array<Buffer, 2> axBuffer; 
  2) Buffer axBuffer;

   void Test(??)/* function argument ?*/

 These are C functions and not C++.

 Can someone please help me in getting the appropriate function prototype for the function named "Test"?

 Advanced thanks.
```

Comment: There is no function overloading in C. It's not possible.

Answer (score 6):

C doesn't have function overloading.  The simplest way to approach this with a single function is to take a pointer-to-`Buffer` and a length:

```
void Test(Buffer *buffer, size_t length);
```

When invoking this function with a single `Buffer`:

```
Buffer buf = ...;
Test(&buf, 1);
```

When invoking it with an `std::array`:

```
std::array<Buffer, 2> buffers = ...;
Test(buffers.data(), buffers.size());
```

If you want the length argument to be optional, you have two use two differently-named functions, unfortunately:

```
void TestOne(Buffer *);
void TestMany(Buffer *, size_t);
```